# ASP.NET and C#: MessageBox not shown when used in combination with Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019, messagebox, page-refresh

In my ASP.NET web form, I need to notify users that their feedback has been submitted. I intend to do so by doing this in my code-behind:

```
protected void lblButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

  Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); //Refresh page 
  Messagebox("Feedback submitted. Click OK to go back.");
  return;
}

public void Messagebox(string xMessage)
{
  Response.Write("<script>alert('" + xMessage + "')</script>");
}
```

However, when I run this, my page gets always refreshed without the message box showing.

If I swap Response.Direct with Messagebox, nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would the message box show? You've initiated a refresh before it can be shown. Perhaps swap those 2 lines of code around.

Comment: Nothing changed - question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Alert is page specific, so even if the alert dialog is shown it will disappear as soon as the client redirects.

What you need is a confirmation page that is returned from the lblButton_Click, which has an 'Ok' button, a hyperlink or a timed js function that changes the address to the page you are wanting to redirect to.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to use Response.Redirect(URL,false) in your code..

```
protected void lblButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

      Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl,false); //Refresh page 
      Messagebox("Feedback submitted. Click OK to go back.");
      return;
    }
```

`Response.Redirect(URL,false):` The client is redirected to a new page and the current page on the server will keep processing ahead.

`Response.Redirect(URL,true):` The client is redirected to a new page, but the processing of the current page is aborted.

Again message is not display then try to use.....Javascript Alert...

```
protected void lblButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl,false); //Refresh page 
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler), typeof(Page), "alert", "javascript:alert('Feedback submitted. Click OK to go back.');", true);
return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following one of the suggestions I got, I ended up using a confirmation page with an OK button which is called from the aspx file:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click" Text="Save"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this thing?');"  />
```